# human voice , FFT

Tags: fft

i have a project ,, its about :
getting the average of human sound ,, the average of frequencies by FFT  for each sound in the language
then reverse the fft to lesten to it ,, and is has to be realizes sound

if am planing to do those steps .. what do u suggest to use to make it works
i mean ,, whats apps for fft can give me a good result , what app can make make good comparison to get the frequencies averages . and what app can reverse fft to realizes the final sound ?

is there is 1 software can make all of those steps ?

Comment: Look up MFCCs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum

Comment: If you dont have the planning of learning a whole new computing language, any audio analyzer program will help you a lot in doing such.